# React navigation drawer dragging wherever in need on screen

Tags: react-native

I tried to open drawer anywhere on screen with dragging drawer by `minSwipeDistance` property of drawer navigator.I tried with this but it didn't work although there wasn't an error.Can anyone recommend me anything to do this? Thanks in advance!

This is my code if anyone needs to be informed additionally.

```
         <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
                <Drawer.Navigator
                    backBehavior='initialRoute'
                    minSwipeDistance={0.7}
                    drawerStyle={{
                    width:Dimensions.get('window').width,

                }} drawerContent={ ()=>{return(<MenuDrawer  ref={menuDrawer} cats={this.state.cat_list}  />) }}>
                    <Drawer.Screen
                        name="MainScreenComponent"
                        component={MainComponent}

                    />
                </Drawer.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
```